How to resolve and plot this integral?
I need to plot this formula for the range d=1 to 4 but am somewhat lost.

The values r, K, f1 and f2 are constants. This is my attempt to resolve the problem.
firstTermTop[\[Theta]_] := r*Sin[\[Theta]];
firstTermBot[\[Theta]_, d_] := d - (r*Cos[\[Theta]]);
secTermTop := K*f1*f2;
secTermBot[\[Theta]_, 
   d_] := (d - (r*Cos[\[Theta]]) )^2 + (r*Sin[\[Theta]])^2;
operandOne[\[Theta]_, d_] := 
  2*Cos[ArcTan[firstTermTop[\[Theta]]/firstTermBot[\[Theta], d]]];
operandTwo[\[Theta]_, d_] := 
  secTermTop[\[Theta]]/secTermBot[\[Theta], d];
flux[\[Theta]_, d_] := operandOne[\[Theta], d]*operandTwo[\[Theta], d];
Integrate[flux[\[Theta], d], {\[Theta], 0, Pi}]

It produces this output, which I find odd given all the constants have disappeared.

(Undeterred, I tried nailing down values for the constants and plotting it, to see the flat line plot.)
Calculating the result by adding many small slices of angles of θ produces 0 at d=0, dropping to -∞ as it approaches r, then flips to ∞ and starts dropping toward 0. This seems logical - the calculation is related to the field flux from a ring, from the center through the edge of the ring itself (of radius r).
Any tips or pointers are appreciated.

you write secTermTop := K*f1*f2; then later you write secTermTop[Theta]  which is it? Is  secTermTop a constant or a function? also better not use upper case K, user lower case k  And why is your screen shot shows lower case cos and tan and so on, then your code is Cos and Tan ? is the screen shot you had there not written in Mathematica?

@Nasser "you write secTermTop := Kf1f2; then later you write secTermTop[Theta] which is it?" The first. My bad. "Is secTermTop a constant or a function?" It resolves to a constant. ".. not written in Mathematica?" That equation was written in Mathematica, it's just that the formula was written as a 'display formula' and I (poorly) chose to use lowercase. I'll change it. Thanks for the tips!

If only plotting is needed, numerical integration is sufficient. Therefore, you can use NIntegrate.
In addition, you need to pay attention to the choice of variable names and the difference between Set and SetDelayed.
k = 1;
f1 = 1;
f2 = 1;
r = 1;
frp[d_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  2 Cos[ArcTan[(r  Sin[\[Theta]])/(d - r  Cos[\[Theta]])]] (
   k  f1  f2)/((d - 
      r Cos[\[Theta]])^2 + (r Sin[\[Theta]])^2), {\[Theta], 
   0, \[Pi]}]
Plot[frp[d], {d, 0, 4}]



Thank you! :) I reproduced your code above and it works (almost(1)) as I expected to plot the equation. Yes, I missed the difference between 'Set' & 'Set Delayed', and had not known to keep the variable names lowercase.  1) I cannot understand why the first part of the plot is going to positive infinity, but am guessing that's a problem with my logic (or math). In any case, this question has been solved thanks to your help.
